# LINQ to XML with multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, linq, namespaces

I hope you can help :-) 
I have gotten stuck in trying to use LINQ to read XML file in C#.

This is the XML structure:

```
<DataBase
xsi:schemaLocation="http://somestuff.new/xml http://somestuff.xsd"
xmlns:ns5="http://somestuff.new/ns5"
xmlns:ns3="http://somestuff.new/ns3"
xmlns:ns2="http://somestuff.new/ns2"
xmlns="http://somestuff.new/ns"
xmlns:xsi="http://somestuff.new/XMLScema-instance"
xmlns:ns4="http://somestuff.new/ns4">
    <Cars>
         <SmallCars attribute="Something">
         <Id>licenceplate</Id>
             <Parts attribute="All Parts">
                <Extras>
                   <Gauges xmlns="http://somestuff.new/ns32>
                      <Speed>100</Speed>
                      <Rpm>3200</Rpm>
                   </Gauges>
                </Extras>
             </Parts>
         </SmallCars>
    </Cars>
</DataBase>
```

I want to read the value from Speed and RPM using LINQ but everything I try seem to fail...

This is one of my attempts:

```
XNamespace ns3 = XNamespace.Get("http://somestuff.new/ns3");
from gaugeElement in extentionElement.Descendants(ns3 + "Gauges")
select new Gauge
{
Speed = tpxElement.Element(ns3 + "Speed") != null ? Convert.ToDouble(tpxElement.Element(ns3 + "Speed").Value) : 0.00,
Rpm = tpxElement.Element(ns3 + "Rpm") != null ? Convert.ToInt32(tpxElement.Element(ns3 + "Rpm").Value) : 0
}
```

I'm using a Gauge class that has to properties:

```
public int Speed { get; set; }
public int Rpm { get; set; }
```

I hope one of you clever guys can provide me with an example on how to get these values or explain why my quest for the values fails :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query expression is declaring a range variable called `gaugeElement`, but you're then using `tpxElement` within your code. I'd also use the conversions supplied by `XElement` to make your code simpler to read - and I wouldn't personally even use a query expression:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "http://somestuff.new/ns3";
        var gauges = doc
            .Descendants(ns + "Gauges")
            .Select(x => new { // You'd use new Gauge here
                Speed = (double?) x.Element(ns + "Speed") ?? 0.0,
                Rpm = (int?) x.Element(ns + "Rpm") ?? 0
            });
        foreach (var gauge in gauges)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(gauge);
        }
    }
}
```

Output (after fixing your XML):

```
{ Speed = 100, Rpm = 3200 }
```

Comment: This works! Can I ask how I could make it work if I would to be making a class of Cars and then doing something like:
var Cars = from car in xml.Descendants(ns + "Cars")
           select new Parts
           {
            Extras = (from extraElement in Parts.Descendants(ns3 + "Gauges").Select(x => new { // You'd use new Gauge here
                Speed = (double?) x.Element(ns3 + "Speed") ?? 0.0,
                Rpm = (int?) x.Element(ns3 + "Rpm") ?? 0
            });

I can't seem to get that to work?

Comment: Sorry for the code in this comment.. I'm new to posting here so I'm not 100% sure on how else to do it? :-)

And by the way thanks for your help so far! :-)

Comment: @Sasquatch: "I can't seem to get that to work" doesn't really say much. This sounds like a different problem, so you should ask a new question showing how far you've got so far and what happens.

Comment: True, I'll ask a new question :-)